# Как загрузить на сервер несколько файлов из формы с помощью jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Имеется форма

```html
     <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
<div><img id="img"><input type="file" id="image" name="image_1" class='uploads' multiple /></div>
<div><img id="img"><input type="file" id="image" name="image_2" class='uploads' multiple /></div>
<div><img id="img"><input type="file" id="image" name="image_3" class='uploads' multiple /></div>
</form>
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите Как загрузить на сервер несколько файлов из формы с помощью jquery ajax. Реально работающего варианта не нашел. Если можно конкретный код.

Comment: Варианты https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously и куча полезных ссылок на готовые решения в ответах

Comment: Этот пост давно отработал. Для одного файла - нет проблем. Проблема в том,  что не нашел работающего решения для описанного случая одновременной загрузки нескольких файлов

Comment: МИ по ссылкам смотрели? - например, http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/, https://danielmg.org/demo/java-script/uploader/basic и тд. из поста

Comment: Если можно конкретный работающий код. Это случай когда впервые не нашел адекватного для себя решения. Лучшая для меня загрузка 1 файла https://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-image-file-using-ajax-and-jquery/, но для нескольких его переделать мне не удалось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По ссылке в Вашем комментарии (глава "4. jQuery"):

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    $(".uploads").each(function(){
      fd.append(this.name, this.files[0]);
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо, за участие. Но результат по прежнему один и тот же - загружается только один файл. Если Вам интересны подробности http://www.sitesnt77.ru/image/.

Comment: @svtdoors Потому что Вы решили упорствовать и делать выборку по `id` - `$("#image")`, хотя я показал Вам, как делать правильно - по классу. Так как предполагается уникальность `id` на странице, выборка по `id` возвращает не больше одного элемента.

Comment: @svtdoors Не говоря уже о том, что мой цикл вообще закомментирован. http://www.sitesnt77.ru/image/form.txt

Comment: Я не упорствую, просто не понимаю, что нужно сделать. В верней части картинки изображен результат с кодом который вы прислали, который позволяет вывести последнюю  (а не первую) из загруженных картинок.

Comment: @svtdoors В PHP-коде Вам нужен цикл по массиву полученных файлов - https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: Возможно и нужен цикл с $_FILES,  но как его делать неизвестно. У меня на сайтах самописная административная панель из которой на сервер загружается одновременно 6 файлов (аналогично инструкции с присланной Вами ссылки) - проблем ноль. Этот же PHP файл все обрабатывает и загружает. Только там простая форма без Ajax - и не каких циклов.  
Спасибо за участие, к сожалению задача оказалась непроста. Буду разбираться с $_FILES, тоже еще проблема.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало с Вашим кодом. Проблема была в том, что в форме файлы должны быть с разными именами, а PHP обработчик должен делать выборку файлов по отправленным (разным) именам. Код в исходной форме (на самом верху поста) исправил.